# Manually installing pyodbc on Windows with firewall

Tags: python, c++, pyodbc

I am trying to install pyodbc on my work machine which has a firewall. So I donwnloaded pyodbc-3.0.7.zip, and tried to install it manually with the following command:

pip install C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\pkgs\pyodbc-3.0.7.zip

But it did not work. From searching around, if I want to continue on in this path, it looks like I need to compile the c++ source.

Is this the only way to go if I want to install pyodbc manually?

Comment: as it is sometimes difficult to install an offline archive which originally was designed to be installed via the web I normally suggest people use a proxy. Would you be able to use a proxy which allows access to the internet ? If yes: better try this.

Comment: Upon your suggestion, I was looking into the proxy option. I happened to try going the executable route per Bryant Eargle, and the executable option worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Select the appropriate `exe` for your CPU architecture from [here](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/downloads/list). Once the executable is downloaded, an active network connection isn't needed.